# Does PoE require impedance matching

Tags: impedance-matching, poe

I'm currently designing a PCB that's powered through Power-over Ethernet. It's my first time working with ethernet on a PCB. I've based the schematic on a Development board by Espressif (Link : https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/hw-reference/esp32/get-started-ethernet-kit.html).

I know that the data line (pin 1 ,2 ,3 & 6 on RJ45) on Ethernet must have impedance matching at 100Ω differential. When it come to the other pin used for the PoE, I didn't find if they need impedance matching (differential) or not?

Thanks for the help

Comment: In passing it's worth noting that the POE 802.3af standard requires that your powered device PD must accept both powering mode A (1+2 and 3+6) and mode B (4+5 and 7+8), with any polarity, and that the choice belongs to the Power Supplying Equipment PSE (802.3 33.2.3, 33.3.1, table 33-13).  So-called "passive POE" is really just "power-over-CAT5" and vendors pretty much do as they please, especially as regards voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does PoE require impedance matching*

PoE can feed power into the ethernet magnetics via the centre taps of the line-side transformer windings. This is a type of phantom-power arrangement and doesn't require any additional impedance matching. You still need the normal impedance matching of course.

There are also [other arrangements of wires](https://support.visiotechsecurity.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014288059-How-to-power-a-passive-RJ45-POE-device) that make use of exclusive (non-data) wires and these also don't need impedance matching: -

[image]